# Recalculate widths - Owl Carousel 2 - Using merge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, owl-carousel

I'm using Owl Carousel 2.2.0.
 [Want to have effect like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b33e8.png)

Here's jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ke1ozzv9/4/

Want to have class "smaller" on first and last visible bottle. Class "small" on 2th and 4th visible.
Also want to recalculate widths and data-merge after each owl change. Center bottle always must have

```
data-merge="3"
```

while the rest have

```
data-merge="1"
```

Pleeease help, I'm sitting with this for 2 days.

Comment: Why can't you do this with css? add margin manually..

Comment: Because it simply doesn't work. Each slide has own width. I want to have center bottle wider.

Comment: what about trigger the event `refresh.owl.carousel` (using `owl.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');`)

Comment: This trigger doesn't work also. It's a bug.

Comment: So I'm sorry I don't know how to help you..